# json values only writing to first field in python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to write csv data (MAC addresses and signal strength values) to a JSON file using Python, but the data is only writing to the first field. How do I get each signal strength value to write to the correct MAC address?

## This is my csv data (total of 30 addresses):

```
    wifi                  rss
    b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:e2   -56
    34:a8:4e:fc:13:50   -59
    34:a8:4e:fd:3c:50   -57
    34:a8:4e:fd:3c:53   -55
    34:a8:4e:fc:13:53   -58
    b0:7f:b9:bc:f1:02   -81
    b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:e0   -55
    ec:58:ea:59:a3:53   -89
    b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:40   -69
    b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:42   -67
    00:1d:7e:42:e0:ba   -60
    b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:f0   -63
    b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:50   -72
    b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:f2   -64
    0a:8d:cb:65:6d:70   -85
    06:8d:cb:65:6d:70   -85
```

## This is my code so far

```
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd

my_csv = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')
fo = open('my_json.json','w')

wifi = my_csv.wifi

f = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv',usecols=[2])
rss = f.rss

fieldnames = (wifi)
reader = csv.DictReader( f, wifi)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, fo, indent = 2)
    fo.write('\n')
```

## this is what I'm getting

```
"b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:e2": "rss",
"34:a8:4e:fc:13:50": null,
"34:a8:4e:fd:3c:50": null,
"34:a8:4e:fd:3c:53": null,
"34:a8:4e:fc:13:53": null,
"b0:7f:b9:bc:f1:02": null,
"b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:e0": null,
"ec:58:ea:59:a3:53": null,
"b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:40": null,
"b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:42": null,
"00:1d:7e:42:e0:ba": null,
"b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:f0": null,
"b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:50": null,
"b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:f2": null,
"0a:8d:cb:65:6d:70": null,
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Note: you can also use `df.to_json`

Comment: all of the null values should be showing the negative values e.g. "0a:8d:cb:65:6d:70": -85,

Comment: Can you post how ur json should like for the above sample in your question ...Ex: `{"b0:7f:b9:bc:f0:e2": "-56", "34:a8:4e:fc:13:50": "-59"}` ?

Comment: Yes it should be as you stated there. "wifi":{  
         "20:25:64:b7:91:40":-73,
         "70:4d:7b:11:3a:c8":-81,
         "88:d7:f6:a7:2a:4c":-39,
         "8c:0f:6f:e7:2b:78":-42,
         "8c:0f:6f:e7:2b:80":-43,
         "92:0f:6f:e7:2b:80":-43,  and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
import json
import pandas as pd

my_csv = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv', sep="\s*")
result = {"wifi": {k:v for k, v in my_csv.to_dict('split')["data"]}}

with open('my_json.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dumping inserting data to json at starting row. Thus it is printing same. You need to append Data. You can append data to any dictionary and dump that complete dictionary to Json

```
    # Out of Loop
    data = {}

    #Inside Loop
    data.append("What ever Json You want to insert")

    #Outside Loop
    json.dump(data, fo,[other arguments])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as jsonfile:
    json.dump(dictionary, jsonfile, indent=4)
```

Note that this should be used after you have created a `dictionary` from wifi and rss.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using pandas you can use
`to_json` method described here

`https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html`

I think for this case the following code should do the trick.

```
import pandas as pd

dataFrame = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')
dataFrame.set_index('wifi').to_json('path_of.json')
```

Comment: is there a way to indent each line with to_json, like you can do with json.dump?

Comment: i didnt get you can you pls explain with this with an example ?

Comment: if you find my answer helpfull please upvote :) thanks